# Compare enum without considering its arguments

Tags: haxe

Let me make this clear, I have this enum:

```
enum Token {
    Number(v:Float);
    Identifier(v:String);
    TString(v:String);
    Var;
    Assign;
    Division;
    // and so on
}
```

I want to check if the value of a variable is an Identifier, but this doesn't work:

```
if(tk == Token.Identifier) {
```

It only allows me to compare the values if I pass arguments:

```
if(tk == Token.Identifier('test')) {
```

But this will only match if the identifier is 'test', but I want to match any identifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Type.enumConstructor(tk) == "Identifier"
```

Read the [Type doc](https://api.haxe.org/Type.html) for more methods on enum.

---

Update (2019-02-04):

At the time of writing this answer it was still Haxe 2.06. Much have changed since then.

At this moment, for Haxe 3 (or 4), I would recommend [pattern matching](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-pattern-matching-introduction.html), specifically using [single pattern check](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-pattern-matching-single.html) instead:

```
if (tk.match(Identifier(_)) ...
```

which is a short hand for

```
if (switch tk { case Identifier(_): true; case _: false; }) ...
```

`_` is the wildcard that matches anything.

Answer (score 3):

alternatively:

```
static function isIdentifier(token : Token) return switch(token) { case Token.Identifier(_): true; default: false; }
```

Using "using" you should also be able to do:

```
if(tk.isIdentifier()) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Or even:

```
tk.match(Token.Identifier(_));
```